# iterm2 not restoring remote SSH session over VPN

Tags: iterm2

Working with macOS Monterey, I am not sure if I understand the `session restore` feature of `iterm2`

I have lot of SSH sessions to remote VMs over VPN. I put the mac to sleep and when I resume, I thought `restore session` thing will kick in and my sessions will be restored.

But it won't work. The terminals just keep sitting there and won't do anything. It's only when I try to type something, they fail with error `$ client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe`

I thought my sessions would be restored when mac is woken. I checked the system settings and iterm2 prefs, the required boxes are checked/unchecked.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: There's nothing a terminal can do when at certain point the *server* notice that you mac "disappeared". Set up something that will retain your shell sessions on the server and use it for your ssh sessions, e.g. `tmux`.

Comment: I am using `screen` on the debian VM

Comment: Looking at the demo-video https://iterm2.com/misc/restoration-demo.mov from iterm2 site, https://iterm2.com/documentation-restoration.html, that guy doesn't seem to be using any `tmux`  or `screen`. He just opens a file in vi, quits iterm2 and then starts it. I tried that test too, doesn't work for me

Comment: What I mean is, even if you use tmux, it doesn't prevent your mac from disconnecting from the server anyway. It merely allows you to go / get back the shell sessions you were you using after you reconnect to the server manually. There may be some way to increase some timeout or whatsoever on the SSH server, but I don't think it will work reliably anyway because of stuff like NAT.